# Unable to fetch (10.04)

Tags: update-manager

Hey guys I recently installed ubunt 10.04 and I want to upgrade to 11.04 (I had a really small flash drive and I could only get 10.04 so I wanted to keep upgrading) But I keep getting unable to fetch now I'm new to using ubuntu so if you guys could help it'd be great

Error message :

```
W:Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you guys also if you guys could make the instructions to fix this really clear because I'm an idiot it'd be appreciated thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

You are using an extremely old release.  Ubuntu 10.04 is out of LTS support and has been deprecated.  You should be using a newer version.  You can get the latest one here:

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

You can reference the releases and support status of each here:

[List of Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)